# Alarm clock with "NumPad digits"

Tags: android

When I type the digits for when the alarm rings, I want it to be in the same layout as when you type the numpad.

7 8 9

4 5 6

1 2 3

Having it 3x3 will make it much faster than sliding Hours and then Minutes.

I want to buy a new app with this functionality.

Comment: The clock app bundled with Cyanogenmod 10.2 works this way (except that the number pad is in phone order and not in keyboard order, is that ok?). If someone knows where to download it, please post an answer.

Comment: Having it 3x3, you can not enter a "0" for e.g. "10:00" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using **[AlarmDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.splunchy.android.alarmclock)** for quite a while now. While on a first look, it also has those "sliding hours and minutes", simply tapping the numbers opens the keypad in the manner you describe, so you simply can type the numbers.

Apart from that, the app is pretty feature-loaden: one-time alarms, repeating alarms, only for specific weekdays, skip once, powernap... And different tricks to prevent "shut up and oversleep", if needed. Ringtones/MP3 can be chosen, or even a radio stream. Speaking clock keeps you informed on the weather (back-fires with bad weather, you might want to stay in bed ;) Spoken text can be adjusted to your gusto, for a personal wake-up ("Good morning Izzy! It's 7:30, weather is cloudy. Currently 18°, expecting up to 27° today and rain...")

[image: Input time with keyboard] [image: Alarms] [image: Snooze]
<sup>*AlarmDroid:* Enter time with keyboard (oder screenshot), list of alarms, alarm fired (click images for larger variants)</sup>

The first (a little older) screenshot demonstrates the feature you're after, the other two a few of the features I've described. Didn't want to overload the post with more screenshots – e.g. from the "math problem solver" to get the alarm of…

There's a fully functional [free version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.splunchy.android.alarmclock) as well as a [donation package](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.splunchy.android.alarmclock.donation) available in the Playstore. So feel free to try before buy. The free version comes with some ads in the config screens, the pro without ads. For more alternatives, be welcome to [browse my list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=95) :)